# Using Laravel passport and Vuejs. Auth::User() doesn't work on blade despite user being authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel passport to authenticate users. From my Vuex store. I dispatch the login action like this:

```
login({ commit}, user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let url = `/auth/login`;
      let email = user.email;
      let password = user.password;

      axios.post(url, { email, password })
      .then(response => {
        const token = response.data.token
        const user = response.data.user

        localStorage.setItem('AnimeStock.jwt', 'Bearer '+ token);
        localStorage.setItem('AnimeStock.user', JSON.stringify(user));

        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ token;

        commit('AUTH_SUCCESS', {token, user});

        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        commit('AUTH_ERROR', error.response.data.error)
        localStorage.removeItem('AnimeStock.jwt')
        localStorage.removeItem('AnimeStock.user')
        reject(error)
      })
    })
  }
```

This works and the user is authenticated. Next, I try to fetch the user from my vue component like this.

```
api.get(`/auth/user`).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
});
```

My API route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    //Auth routes
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

It hits my AuthController and returns the current logged in user.

```
public function user()
{
     $user = Auth::user();
     return response()->json($user);
}
```

This is working fine **BUT** when I do this on my layout blade file, it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    @auth
      window.User= {!! json_encode(Auth::user(), true) !!};
    @else
      window.User= [];
    @endauth
</script>
```

This doesn't work either

```
@php
$user = Auth::user()->id
@endphp
```

Comment: what "doesn't work"? and what route is returning a view that extends that layout?

Comment: @lagbox calling Auth::user() doesn't work on blade. It returns null. IIt only works when I call an api request to fetch it. This is a SPA so no child views.  I am using json web token as auth